# TextMate indentation "navigation" as in Notepad++

Tags: textmate, syntax-highlighting

I want to duplicate the function from Notepad++ where you can easily view your indentation in your code.

[image]

I want the dotted border that is lined within the indent. Is there a plugin for this? Or can you expand the feature where the PHP scope gets a lighter background color, so that the space within the PHP tag is highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working TextMate at hand (new machine, don't use TM anymore) but there is a preference or a menu entry somewhere to "show invisible characters".

It shows a little right-pointing triangle for each tab/indentation level which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Can't find it, http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2005-January/002320.html

Comment: Look again. (one of) The cool thing(s) with GUI apps on a Mac is that it's very "discoverable": all the functions are available from the menu bar and all the apps' basic menus are laid out almost exactly the same way with very distinctive names. For example the function you want has something to do with how TextMate displays text so your two best bets are the "View" and the "Text" menus. The next step is to click on one of these menus — let's start with the first, "View" — and look for a "Show Invisibles" entry. If you don't find one click on the second menu.